# A weaker condition than Lagrangian for groups

Tags: group-theory

If $ G $ is a group that possesses the property that for every divisor $ n $ of $ |G| $, $ G $ contains a subgroup of order $ n $, then $ G $ is called a Lagrangian or CLT group.

But what about this property: whenever $ |G| = mn $ where $ m $ and $ n $ are coprime, then $ G $ contains a subgroup of order $ n $. Does this concept have a name? And is there a systematic way to figure out, for any given group (say $ A_5 $), whether it has this property or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These groups are called solvable.

Of course, being solvable is usually defined as having all composition factors be abelian, but it is a result of Hall that this is equivalent to your condition.

Such subgroups (i.e. ones whose order and index are coprime) are called Hall subgroups.